# Why do electrical storms cause metal objects to vibrate?

Tags: electricity, atmospheric-science, electrical-engineering

I am curious about the vibration of metal objects as a sign of an impending lightening strike. This is apparently a common occurrence; so much so that a quick google search will yield many pages instructing people to head for shelter if their keys (other other small metal objects) start to vibrate in the midst of an electrical storm.

One climbing site even mentions that a vibrating rope is a sign of a lightening strike.

Can someone explain the mechanism behind this? My guess is that it a piezo electric effect, though this contradicts my (limited) understanding that atmospheric electricity is static.

Thanks :)

Comment: Hello Serge. Could you provide some _credible_ references for these claims?

Comment: Like I said, a quick google search would yield plenty... from the National Weather Service:"Light metal objects vibrate or buzz     " https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjABahUKEwj5m_7t4sDHAhWNEpIKHVqBDEs&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.weather.gov%2Fmedia%2Fpah%2FWeatherEducation%2Flightningsafety.pdf&ei=0Y7aVbnvK42lyATagrLYBA&usg=AFQjCNFCeHZfItcMi8Ki0NzcvT-c2Ed8zg&sig2=LhbcHBg4K8_hlp-aivK1kA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lightnings primarily depend on strong electrostatic fields. They're up to 100 volts per meter in the summer and 500 volts per meter in the winter. These fields are fluctuating. When a certain critical threshold not far from those values is reached, a lightning strikes.

Does the electrostatic field move a metal?

There is no direct electrostatic force acting on the keys because they keys' total electric charge is basically zero. That's true even if the electric field of the thunderstorm depends on location and time.

However, the metallic object gets charged locally. The electric field polarizes the keys. It means that one side of the keys (measured relatively to the direction of the electrostatic field of the thunderstorm) is positively charged while the opposite side is negatively charged.

The total force acting on this polarized object would be zero if the electrostatic field were uniform and constant in time. But when the electric field is non-uniform (which may also be guaranteed by its being time-dependent because the signals only propagate by the speed of light), there will be a net force acting on the keys.

I am not able to produce any numbers now but the keys (or metallic object) get the charge $+Q$ coulombs in the upper part of the keys and the opposite charge $-Q$ coulombs on the lower side. Because the electric field depends on the altitude and oscillates, the electric field may be higher on the upper side of the keys than on the opposite one, and there will be a net force. The electric field may fluctuate. When the object is light enough relatively to the length in the relevant direction, the electrostatic force will be enough to move the keys or make them oscillate.

What really matters is some ratio of the length to the width etc. Even bad conductors may get polarized and exhibit the same effect – which is why long ropes, perhaps especially wet ones, can oscillate.

Comment: What would determine the frequency of the "buzz"? This happened to my uncle's metal gear when he got caught in a storm on a ledge halfway up Fairview Dome in Yosemite. He said the buzz was "kind of high pitched".

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure about the answer to the interesting question. But as far as I can say, there is no reason why the lightnings should cause any quasiperiodic i.e. vibrating response at all. So I believe that the vibrations of the metal gear have a frequency determined by the geometry and tension in the metal gear itself while the lightning is just an irrelevant choice of the spark. So I think that the frequency of the buzz would be the same if you made it vibrate mechanically or by some other means. Just like metallic musical instruments that simply vibrate at some frequencies.